# About operator overload

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, codeblocks, ifstream

I have a program in `c++` that overload this operator `>>`. This operator is in charge of asking for a text entry `cin >>` My question is what do I have to do in case I have to use this same operator but for a `ifstream` entry.

EDITED with code

```
istream & operator >> (istream & Read, Person & ObjPers) {
     cout << "\ n \ n Enter name of Person:";
     Lee >> ObjPers.NomPers;
     cout << "\ n \ n Enter year of birth:";
     Read >> ObjPers.AnioNac;
     cout << "\ n \ nEnter place of birth:";
     Read >> ObjPers.LugNac;
     cout << "\ n \ nIs it alive ?:";
     Read >> ObjPers.Vive;
     return Read;
}
```

If I need use the same operator but with a different use as `ifstream >> variable` What I need do ?

EDIT2:

When I overload ostream << this happens:

```
   ostream & operator << (ostream & Write, Persona & ObjPers) {
    Write << "\ n \ nData of the Person \ n";
    Type << "\ nName:" << ObjPers.NomPers;
    Write << "\ nPlace of birth:" << ObjPers.LugNac;
    Write << "\ nYear of birth:" << ObjPers.AnioNac;
    if (ObjPers.live == 1)
    Write << "\ nIt is alive. \ N";
    else
    Write << "\ nNot alive. \ N";
         return Write;

    }
```

I when i try to use ofstream with << operator I can't the overloaded operator runs first

```
void BinaryTree <T> :: Save (NodeTree <T> * p, ofstream & out)
{
     if (p) {

        Save (p-> Sonleft, out);
         exit << p-> Info;

        Save (p-> SonRigth, out);

     }
     cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Let's see your code.

Comment: Usually nothing. A stream is a stream.

Comment: I edit the post  with a code

Comment: @MarcoLeslie `std::istream` is the base class for the stream classes.  There is nothing you need to do.  On that note, why didn't you simply try using a different stream?  You would have seen it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you implement the `operator>>` function,

1. Don't use  `std::cin` or `std::cout` in its implementation.
2. Assume that the user knows what to enter for such an object.
3. Use fully qualified names for `istream`, i.e. use `std::istream& Read` insted of `istream& Read`.

My suggestion for your function:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Person & ObjPers) {
   in >> ObjPers.NomPers;
   in >> ObjPers.AnioNac;
   in >> ObjPers.LugNac;
   in >> ObjPers.Vive;
   return in;
}
```

or combine the statements to one:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Person & ObjPers) {
   return (in >> ObjPers.NomPers
              >> ObjPers.AnioNac
              >> ObjPers.LugNac
              >> ObjPers.Vive);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that when I try to use ifstream with the same operator >> the overload is executed

Comment: @MarcoLeslie, You make it sound like that's a drawback. From my point of view, that's expected and is good.

Comment: It's a problem because I need read from a file an when I try to read my program crash because  the overload

Comment: @MarcoLeslie, that's a different problem. Perhaps you don't have the right data in the file, or not managing the `ifstream` object correctly. It's hard telling what the problem could be unless you post a [mcve].